# RabbitMQ fails if client becomes unavailable

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I use Celery (3.1.25) with RabbitMQ (3.6.5) as a broker. They are running in AWS environment. I use celery workers aggressively - I create new servers and run new celery workers there, then after some time I simply kill the server with AWS API. It seems the processes have some time to shutdown and send "EXIT" signal to the broker. But later the whole server becomes unavailable as AWS terminates it.

And then RabbitMQ crashes and restarts, all active connections get lost.

I see the following in the logs:

```
=CRASH REPORT==== 22-Nov-2016::18:04:33 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: rabbit_reader:init/4
    pid: <0.25989.133>
    registered_name: []
    exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,nxdomain}
      in function  rabbit_nodes:cluster_name_default/0 (src/rabbit_nodes.erl, line 215)
      in call from rabbit_nodes:cluster_name/0 (src/rabbit_nodes.erl, line 210)
      in call from rabbit_reader:server_properties/1 (src/rabbit_reader.erl, line 281)
      in call from rabbit_reader:start_connection/3 (src/rabbit_reader.erl, line 1091)
      in call from rabbit_reader:handle_input/3 (src/rabbit_reader.erl, line 1041)
      in call from rabbit_reader:recvloop/4 (src/rabbit_reader.erl, line 446)
      in call from rabbit_reader:run/1 (src/rabbit_reader.erl, line 428)
      in call from rabbit_reader:start_connection/4 (src/rabbit_reader.erl, line 386)
    ancestors: [<0.25987.133>,<0.4726.0>,<0.4725.0>,<0.4724.0>,rabbit_sup,
                  <0.117.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',#Port<0.213814>,normal}]
    links: [<0.25987.133>]
    dictionary: [{process_name,
                      {rabbit_reader,
                          <<"172.31.9.14:51372 -> 172.31.11.84:5672">>}}]
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 1598
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 1224
  neighbours:
```

As I got it - it tries to resolve sender's name/IP but without success and fails.

What should I do to prevent him from crashing?